# Google maps v3: Show multiple markers at once

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps API v3 to add markers to a map. 
All the markers have a custom image as the icon.

I have some filters that the users can click to hide/show the markers on the map.
Basically what I do on the filters is iterate the markers collection and call setVisible for all of them (with true/false accordingly).
The problem I'm having is that when I hide several markers they all disappear at once but when I show the icons they show up slowly (it takes a couple of seconds for 40 markers to become visible).

Is there a way to make all the markers appear at once?

I thought about using a MarkerManager, but it seems to be oriented to something different.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you include a link to what you have so far or include the code?

Comment: When you use setVisible method only the visibility of marker divs is affected so it does not matter if the icons are custom. Unless you somehow reinitialize the map or your filtering function is inefficient you should not see any lag. Please post some code.

Comment: As soon as I have some time I'll post my code. It's strange though, since the markers are displayed very fast if I'm using the default markers (i.e. without my custom image).

Answer (score 0):

Try [markerclusterer.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js?r=360) from google. Demo example in [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/toomanymarkers/toomanymarkers.html). Hope it helps.